# i use paypal but return responce in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Hi  Recently I Was use Paypal Sanbox and it work perfect .
my Question is when payment done by use or cancal i am not getting any response many document say use paypay ipn but is it necessary?
second is when user cancal payment then return in my controller but user close browser tab then not return

Model:

```
  public class PayPalModel
{

    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public string business { get; set; }
    public string no_shipping { get; set; }
    public string @return { get; set; }
    public string cancel_return { get; set; }
    public string notify_url { get; set; }
    public string currency_code { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string actionURL { get; set; }
    public PayPalModel(bool useSandbox)
    {
        this.cmd = "_xclick";
        this.business = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["business"];
        this.cancel_return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cancel_return"];
        this.@return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["return"];
        if (useSandbox)
        {
            this.actionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test_url"];
        }
        else
        {
            this.actionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Prod_url"];
        }

        this.notify_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["notify_url"];

        this.currency_code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["currency_code"];

    }
```

**Controller** :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult RedirectFromPaypal()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult CancelFromPaypal()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult NotifyFromPaypal()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //  [Authorize(Roles="Customers")]
   // [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateCommand(string product, string totalPrice)
    {
        bool useSandbox = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSandbox"]);
        var paypal = new PayPalModel(useSandbox);
        paypal.item_name = product;
        paypal.amount = totalPrice;
        return View(paypal);
        // return View();
    }
```

`WebConfig`:

```
 <add key="business" value="MyPaypalAc@gmail.com" />
<add key="IsSandbox" value="true" />
<add key="currency_code" value="USD" />
<add key="return" value="http://localhost/PayPal/RedirectFromPaypal" />
<add key="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/PayPal/CancelFromPaypal" />
<add key="notify_url" value="http://localhost/PayPal/NotifyFromPaypal" />

<add key="test_url" value="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" />
<add key="Prod_url" value="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" />
```

any idea which paypal method use to know payment done or cancal by user and redirect to my web page
thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally many example show and i was use IPN

Hear IPN Controller

```
 public ActionResult IPN()
    {
        SmartQueueContext context = new SmartQueueContext();
        //   var order = new Order(); // this is something I have defined in order to save the order in the database

        // Receive IPN request from PayPal and parse all the variables returned
        var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate"); //notify-synch_notify-validate
        //   formVals.Add("at", "this is a long token found in Buyers account"); // this has to be adjusted
        // formVals.Add("tx", Request["tx"]);

        // if you want to use the PayPal sandbox change this from false to true
        string response = GetPayPalResponse(formVals, false);

        if (response.Contains("VERIFIED"))
        {
            //string transactionID = GetPDTValue(response, "txn_id"); // txn_id //d
            // string sAmountPaid = GetPDTValue(response, "mc_gross"); // d
            //string deviceID = GetPDTValue(response, "custom"); // d
            //string payerEmail = GetPDTValue(response, "payer_email"); // d
            //string Item = GetPDTValue(response, "item_name");

            //validate the order
            string transactionID = Request["txn_id"];
            string sAmountPaid = Request["mc_gross"];
            string payerEmail = Request["payer_email"]; // d
            context.PayPalTransfer(SessionManager.ClientId, transactionID, payerEmail);


            return RedirectToAction("Summary", "PackageSetup");

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CancelFromPaypal", "PayPal");
        }
       // return RedirectToAction("Index", "PackageSetup");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of IPN for Website Payments Standard is recommended because there are no guarantees that all buyers are going to be redirected to your return URL after payment is completed.

You could enable Auto Return in your PayPal account (direct link to this section https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments ) but even then you need to consider:

- Auto Return it's not instant. There will be a message displayed to the buyers for a few seconds:

"We are redirecting you back to (Seller) website"

Some buyers may close the browser's window/tab instead of waiting.

- Auto Return won't work for payments made by a credit/debit card directly, without a PayPal account.

These buyers will need to click on the "Return to (Seller)" button to be redirected back to your site, and some of them may miss this link.

With IPN enabled, you will always receive asynchronously a POST from PayPal containing the transaction details, regardless if the buyers were returned to your site or not.

Comment: Also, regarding your question about buyers closing the tab without completing the payment, there is not much you can do to track them unless they have clicked on the "Cancel URL" link. 

Maybe you can keep an internal count of all buyers redirected to PayPal from your site. This way, if you add up the ones that completed a payment plus the ones that clicked on the Cancel URL, the ones left will roughly amount to those that abandoned the payment page (without clicking on Cancel URL).

Comment: thanks PayPal_Nacho for give me your valuable time    i try ipn and if any Question then comment you    thanks again